# ¿Como accedo a mi contexto en asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

buenos dias, lo que pasa es que tengo un problema cuando quiero llamar al ApplicationDbContext de mi aplicacion, osea, necesito llamar a mi proveedor que contiene todas mis colleciones de datos, pero me marca un error porque el ApplicacionDbContext tiene una parametro en su constructor y no se entonces como acceder a mi proveedor de datos.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        //if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
            //miguel
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.UserName, Email = Input.Email, PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            var user1 = new Usuario();
            user1.Nombre = Input.UserName;
            user1.Correo = Input.Email;
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext(new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>());
            context.Usuario.Add(user1);
        //}

        //    if (result.Succeeded)
        //    {
        //        _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

        //        var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        //        var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
        //            "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
        //            pageHandler: null,
        //            values: new { userId = user.UserName, code = code },
        //            protocol: Request.Scheme);

        //        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
        //            $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

        //        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        //        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        //    }
        //    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        //    {
        //        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        //    }
        //}

        //// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

}

El metodo OnPostAsync() lo genero el scalfolding, sin embargo, lo que hace es agregarme a las tablas que se generan por default por el identity, lo que vendrian siendo el "dboAspUser" y esas tablas, pero yo no necesito eso, lo que necesito es guardarlos en mis tablas, en ese intento que ven ahí lo unico que trato de hacer es obtener mi contexto y guardarlo en la variable context, despues acceder a la coleccion de usuarios de contexto y agregar ese usuario, pero no puedo hacerlo de esa forma y no se me ocurre otra.

Esta es mi clase de contexto.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public   ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Tribu>().HasKey(d => d.Id);
        builder.Entity<Viaje>().HasKey(d => d.Id);
        builder.Entity<Usuario>().HasKey(d => d.Id);
        builder.Entity<Vehiculo>().HasKey(d => d.Placa);
        builder.Entity<UsuarioTribu>().HasKey(d => new { d.UsuarioId, d.TribuId });
        builder.Entity<UsuarioViaje>().HasKey(d => new { d.UsuarioId, d.ViajeId });

    }

    public DbSet<CarpoolingV2.Models.Viaje> Viaje { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CarpoolingV2.Models.Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CarpoolingV2.Models.Vehiculo> Vehiculo { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CarpoolingV2.Models.Tribu> Tribu { get; set; }


}
```

Este es el error que me manda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar DI para inyectar tu contexto tal y como se ve al principio de tu controlador, ejemplo con UserManager.

```
private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
//Declaras el DbContext a utilizar
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

//lo Inyectas en el controlador
public RegisterModel(
    UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
    ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
    IEmailSender emailSender, ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _context = context
}
```

de esta manera ya puedes llamar a _context.* en tu controlador